# Using selenium on Itunes web site

Tags: python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, app-store-connect

I would like to connect to [Itunes web site](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa) using selenium

Here is the start of the code I use currently:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa')
login_form = browser.find_element_by_id('appleId')
```

It is really basic but somehow, it is not working. 
I get the "appleId" from the webpage when I inspect the element with Firefox.

```
<input id="appleId" class="si-text-field" type="email" can-field="accountName" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" placeholder="Apple ID"></input>
```

But that is apparently not the right way to do it. 
How can I locate the appleId and Password field ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The element which you are trying to look for is within an `iframe`. Try this:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa')

# Add this line
browser.switch_to.frame('authFrame')

login_form = browser.find_element_by_id('appleId')
...
```

Comment: You can just replace `browser.switch_to.frame(browser.find_element_by_id("authFrame")` with `browser.switch_to.frame("authFrame")`.

Comment: @alecxe - Thanks for the suggestion. Made the changes. :)